# HIve query for insert overwrite into table

Tags: hadoop, hive, bigdata, hiveql

`insert overwrite table test_data_type select name, decabs(cast(salary as double)) from test_data_type;`

Hi here the data type of the salary is decimal(10,6) and i am trying to remove the trailing zeroes and insert the data into the same table, here the select is working but when i try to insert the data it is inserting with trailing zeros.
eg:- 10.21010
expected output in the table - 10.2101

Any suggestion thanks.

Answer (score 0):

you can not do it. Hive automatically includes 0s in the end.
But if you need to display without a trailing 0, you can convert it to a string and the trim 0s from it.

```
select rtrim( cast(123.01000 as string),'0')
```

Comment: I need to do it for an entire column and reflect this changes in the table

Comment: I am curious ont why do you need it? Your values arent changing... you can display or download using my formula.

Comment: I think we cannot insert the resulted values from the query cause even if we insert it back to the table as the data type decimal(10,6) it will add trailing zeroes.

Comment: And only why to have required number of zeroes is to change the data type to double and this will remove the trailing zeroes.

Comment: i dint understand why you want to remove 0s but it changing this to double helps then its fibbe

Comment: I have a use case where we are not considering zeroes of calculation in and inserting it back to the table, any ways thanks for the input.

Answer (score 0):

It`s a feature. Hive will pad Decimal numbers with trailing zeros to the scale of the column.

If you want to use Decimal Type, you should accept this feature.

You can get some information from here: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HIVE-12063